# How can I get my page to display scaled without scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So a buddy of mine encountered an issue, the website displays properly when on a screen that's 1440px by 1024px, however on a smaller screen you have to scroll to see further down. We've both been searching and can't figure it out, now it could be the fact that it's made primarily from pngs that the scaling doesn't work properly or it could also be that we're both idiots and it's actually very simple, whichever the case we can't figure it out So hopefully someone can. Overflow-y:hidden will not fix the problem as that would only prevent scrolling and the content of the page stays as is. We've also tried getting JS to detect the window size and it also doesn't seem to work.

Here it is at 100% zoom on a 1366px by 768px screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIxex.jpg

This is what he wants it to look like without the scrolling of course (This is at 65% zoom same screen)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoGmW.jpg

Here's the CSS and HTML (it won't run due to missing files but I assume the issue would be in these)

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
  
  
}

body{
  background: url("../img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.margin-15{
  margin-top: 7%;
}
.container-fluid{
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.Rectangle{
  width: 168px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background-color: #292929;
  left: 43%;
  top: 28.3%;
}
.Rectangle p{
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top: 6%;
  width: 185.2px;
  height: 34.3px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.Rectangle p span{
  color: #a3e8f5;
}
.navBar1 img{
  max-width: 40%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  object-fit: contain;
}


/**.col-xs-3 .atomix{
  padding-top: 4%;
}
.col-xs-3 .Rectangle{
  margin-top: 20%;
}
.col-xs-3 .navBar1{
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}
.col-xs-3 .atomix{
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.col-xs-3 .forums{
  margin-top: -5%;
}
.col-xs-3 .discord{
  margin-top: 4%;
} **/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home | Lectric</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\master.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/leonardosnt/mc-player-counter@1.1.1/dist/mc-player-counter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-3 margin-3">
          <div class="atomix">
          <img src="img\atomix.png" alt="Atomix" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block"/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-3">
            <div class="Rectangle playersOnline mx-auto d-block">
              <p><span data-playercounter-ip="atomixprison.net">0</span> online</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-3">
    <div class="navBar1">
      <img src="img/NavBar1.png" class="img-responsive mx-auto d-block" alt="navbar"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row margin-4 margin-15">
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 mb-0">
        <div class="webStore">
          <a href="https://atomixnetwork.buycraft.net/"><img src="img/webstore.png" alt="webstore" class="mx-auto d-block img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 mt-xl-5 col-md-5 mb-md-0">
        <div class="forums">
          <a href="https://www.atomixprisonmc.net/"><img src="img/forums.png" alt="forums" class="mx-auto d-block img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 mb-0">
        <div class="discord">
          <a href="https://discord.gg/D63c9JM"><img src="img/discord.png" alt="discord" class="mx-auto d-block img-responsive"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#body').css('min-height', '100%');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO, i'm 100% certain that it has a scroll on my screen because of the odd sizing HOW ever the issue was resolved, it turns out the person who was receiving the website didn't have their zoom set to 100% so it looked weird for them..... *sigh*... some people....